# Error occurred in deployment step ‘Activate Features’: Feature with Id is not installed in this farm, and cannot be added to this scope

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, visual-studio-2015

Problem:

> Error occurred in deployment step ‘Activate Features’: Feature with Id is not installed in this farm, and cannot be added to this scope

I understand multiple blogs available for this to answer to user PowerShell command to deploy the Solution.

When I do deployment using PowerShell it works as expected but using Visual studio it throws the Error as above. Our client arguing that in SharePoint 2010 using VS 2010 he was able to deploy but now he is not when using SharePoint 2016 server and Visual studio 2015

What could be the real reason of this error?

Answer (score 0):

In case of a multi server farm you will always face this problem with Visual Studio. Because the deployment step is intended only for a single local server. If you have the problem in a single local server try set the property "Always force install " of the Feature to "True".

Comment: Thanks for response plero. I am aware of this. I am looking for some credible MS source where it got mentioned its not possible. Even I have ms tech community link where it got mentioned. I am looking for if any KB article by Microsoft mentioned these things. I have to convince my business people and they need resouce of MS to say this

Comment: The only article that talk about it almost officially is that: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/calvarro/2011/11/06/sharepoint-2010-visual-studio-2010-error-ocurred-activate-features-feature-with-id-installed-in-this-farm-cannot-be-added-to-this-scope/